# How do we perform groupby operation on data fetched from a database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
string date = DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString();
var grouped = from a in db.Logs
    group a by a.email
    into g
    select new
    {
        intime = (from x in db.Logs where x.date == date && x.email == "" select x.login).Min();
        outime = (from x in db.Logs where x.date == date && x.email == "" select x.login).Min()

    };
return View();
```

I am using a table having `email` and `login_time`.

I need to group them based on `email` and from that I need to get the min `login_time` of a particular `email_id` for current date. I use `min` function to find the first login.
I am very new to LINQ
My table has the field
1.login
2.logout
3.email
4.username

Whenever user login, table gets populated with login time ,logout time,email,username.
=>I need to classify those details based on email for the current date.
so that admin view page should have only the first login and last logout for particular email for the current date.

Comment: Did you mean to tag this with C#?  It isn't C.

Comment: You should get the database to do the grouping — your application should not need to do it.  How you do that with LINQ is a separate discussion; there are others who can help you on that (and I can't — I've not used LINQ).

Comment: I got the database and i converted them in tolist;

Answer (score 0):

```
string date = DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString();
var grouped = from a in db.Logs.ToList()
    where a.date == date
    group a by a.email
    into g
    let ordered = g.OrderBy(x => x.date).ToList()
    let firstLogin = ordered.First()
    let lastLogin = ordered.Last()
    select new
    {
        first_login_time = firstLogin.login_time,
        first_login = firstLogin.login,
        last_login_time = lastLogin.login_time,
        last_login = lastLogin.login        
    };
```

### Update

> admin view page should have only the first login and last logout for
>   particular email for the current date.

```
string date = DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString();
var grouped = from a in db.Logs.ToList()
    where a.login.Date == date
    group a by a.email
    into g
    let firstLogin = g.OrderBy(x => x.login).First() // order by login time and get first
    let lastLogout = g.OrderBy(x => x.logout).Last() // order by lotgout time and get last
    select new
    {
        email: g.Key,
        first_login = firstLogin.login, // first login
        last_logout = lastLogin.logout // last logout
    };
```

I hope your `login` and `logout` fields has type `datetime`. You stil did don get question more clear. When I ask you to get table schema, I supposed you get me somting like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Logs](
    [username] [nvarchar](4000) NOT NULL,
    [email] [nvarchar](4000) NOT NULL,
    [login] [datetime] NULL,
    [logout] [datetime] NULL
)
```

Or maybe class declaration

```
public class Log {
  public string email {get; set; }
  public string username {get; set; }
  public DateTime login {get; set; }
  public DateTime logout {get; set; }

}
```

You may learn how to ask questions

### Update 2

> suppose i have 3 different email.    If they accessed my application
>   there login time and and logout time is recorded.

```
Table[Login_details]
id  employee    date        login   logout  email
1   ShobaBTM    2019-03-18  16:12   16:12   shobabtm@gmail.com
2   neymarjr    2019-03-18  16:22   16:22   neymar@gmail.com
3   Cristiano   2019-03-18  16:23   16:23   cr7@gmail.com
4   neymarjr    2019-03-18  16:25   16:25   neymar@gmail.com
5   neymarjr    2019-03-18  16:30   16:32   neymar@gmail.com
6   neymarjr    2019-03-18  16:42   16:45   neymar@gmail.com
```

> In admin view I should have this

```
1   ShobaBTM    2019-03-18  16:12   16:12   
2   Cristiano   2019-03-18  16:23   16:23
3   neymarjr    2019-03-18  16:25   16:45
```

Well, try this:

```
string date = DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString();
var grouped = from a in db.Logs.ToList()
    where a.date == date
    group a by new { a.employee, a.date }
    into g
    let firstLogin = g.OrderBy(x => TimeSpan.ParseExact(x.login, "hh\\:mm")).First() // order by login time and get first
    let lastLogout = g.OrderBy(x => TimeSpan.ParseExact(x.logout, "hh\\:mm")).Last() // order by logout time and get last
    select new
    {
        employee = g.Key.employee,
        date = g.Key.date,
        first_login = firstLogin.login, // first login
        last_logout = lastLogin.logout // last logout
    };
```

Is that code work? If no - what exactly happens?

Comment: I need to group them based on email and from that I need to get the First login_time of a particular email_id for current date(let it be today).

Comment: I edit answer. You need to provide `Logs` table schema, nobody knows your field names.

Comment: Given. please check it out

Comment: You are super awesome. Worked well. Thanks. Suggest a way to be good  in this

Comment: To be good in what? :) C#, LINQ, ASP.NET MVC? You must read documentation, examples, try to write your own code, experimenting with that, search answers in stackoverflow, and so on. Clarity will come with experience. My own experience in C# is about 10 years, so questions like yours are simple to me :)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> I need to group them based on email and from that I need to get the min login_time of a particular email_id for current date.

For this I'd use the [Queryable.GroupBy with an ElementSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Queryable_GroupBy__4_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___2___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2____3___).

```
DateTime selectionDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;  // or any other date you want to use


var result = db.Logs
    // Keep only logs that have an e-mail on the selection date:
    .Where(log => log.LogInTime == selectionDate)

    // Group all remaining logs into logs with same email
    .GroupBy(log => log.email,

    // element selector: I only need the LoginTimes of the Logs
    log => log.LoginTime,

    // result selector: take the email, and all logInTimes of logs 
    // with this email to make a new object
    (email, logInTimesForThisEmail) =>  new
    {
        Email = email, // only if desired in your end result

        // Order the loginTimes and keep the first,
        // which is the min login time of this email on this date
        MinLoginTimeOnDate = logInTimesForThisEmail
            .OrderBy(logInTime => loginTime)
            .FirstOrDefault(),
```

Your example code shows that you also want the max login time on the selected date. Use a separate Select, so you'll have to order the elements only once:

```
(email, logInTimesForThisEmail) =>  new
{
    Email = email, // only if desired in your end result
    LogInTimes = logInTimesForThisEmail
        .OrderBy(loginTime => loginTime);
})
.Select(groupResult => new
{
    Email = groupResult.Email,
    MinTime = groupResult.LogInTimes.FirstOrDefault(),
    MaxTime = groupResult.LogInTimes.LastOrDefault(),
});
```

If you need more fields than just the Email and the LoginTimes,, change the `ElementSelector` parameter of the GroupBy, such that it contains also these other fields.